# UICollectionView cell creation bypassed `willDisplay cell:` call?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an UICollectionView with `.layer.masksToBounds` set to `false`.

I do this so that way I can achieve a fade-out effect of any cells that scroll out of the collection view's proper bounds.

In order to ensure that I don't display out of bounds cells (when the UICollectionView loads them in), I use the delegate callback:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   // pseudo code
   if !cell.frame.intersects(collectionView.frame) {
      cell.alpha = 0
   }
}
```

However, it appears this callback is not invoked when the CollectionView populates an out-of-bound cell?

While obviously I am always informed if a cell is constructed through the cell provider function (i.e. the function where I invoke the `dequeueReusableCell` call), I cannot determine whether the cell I construct is out of bounds.

Is there any way I can be informed of when the UICollectionView constructs an out-of-bounds cell?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question, do you want to fade out effect from any cel that scroll out of collection view cell or when the cell is gonna be displayed in collection view.

Comment: Both. I have constructed a function that calculates and sets the cell alpha. That is not the problem.

The problem is that I want to ensure the collectionview bounds don't "cut off" the cell, so I set the `.masksToBounds` property to be false. However, it also means any new cell constructed is displayed